# How can one prevent certain attributes from being added to the bundle's manifest with the Maven Bundle Plugin?

Tags: java, maven, osgi, maven-bundle-plugin

I would like to remove certain headers from my release jars (e.g. "Built-by").

I have read that setting the headers to an empty content should do the trick, but it's not working for me. For example, I'm using:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-bundle-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.7</version>
    <extensions>true</extensions>
    <configuration>
        <instructions>
            <Built-By>a</Built-By>
            <Build-Jdk></Build-Jdk>
            <Created-By></Created-By>
            <Somethng-else>Hello</Somethng-else>
        </instructions>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

While `Something-else` is being added, all the other headers (e.g. `Built-By`) remain. Any insights? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<_removeheaders>Build-*</_removeheaders>
```

Nice to hear you find the plugin annoying (without seeming to have looked for the [manual](http://bnd.bndtools.org)).

Comment: Well, it can be quite annoying, but I also said I can't live without it ;) Regarding the manual, I have no idea how I should have gone from what I thought was the [maven-bundle plugin manual](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/felix/releases/maven-bundle-plugin-2.3.7/doc/site/index.html) to [BND's](http://www.aqute.biz/Bnd/Format). Trust me, I have googled for this ;)

Comment: Regarding `<_removeheaders>Build-*</_removeheaders>` I can see it's a BND option, but I'm not sure it's exposed by the maven-bundle-plugin. At the very least, it does not help if I put it in place of `<instructions>` on my original question. Any insights? And thanks a lot for your work on BND!!!

Comment: Ok, so, this `<_removeheaders>` goes inside <instructions>. Working. Thanks!

Comment: Though the maven bundle plugin (annoyingly) adds some extra 'features' for 'user friendliness' it provides access to ALL bnd's features. They are described here http://www.aqute.biz/Bnd/Format :-)

Comment: Just remember that bnd instructions starting with "-" (hyphen) have to be translated to "_" underscore, because XML element names cannot begin with "-". Thanks for that, W3C....

Comment: This answer is not complete. I have no idea how to modify the pom file in order to get the requested result. Can you please update the text to gie a complete answer?

Comment: Since the documentation links in the comments above are now broken, I'll mention this other SO answer that demonstrates how to remove multiple headers: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18505535/171452 (in case anyone, like myself, needs to do that).

Answer (score 0):

I use maven-jar-plugin and thi is my pice of pom:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.2</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <goals>
                <goal>test-jar</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
    <configuration>
        <archive>
            <manifest>
               <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
               <mainClass>...MyClass</mainClass>
               <classpathPrefix>libs/</classpathPrefix>
               <addDefaultImplementationEntries>true</addDefaultImplementationEntries>
            </manifest>
            <manifestEntries>
                <Built-By>a</Built-By>
                <Build-Jdk></Build-Jdk>
                <Created-By></Created-By>
                <Somethng-else>Hello</Somethng-else>
            </manifestEntries>
        </archive>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Comment: Thanks! Trouble is, annoying as the maven-bundle-plugin can be, I absolutely need it for things like import/export package generation :)