# How to configure maven-bundle-plugin to exclude Import-Service and Export-Service?

Tags: osgi, fuseesb

I use maven-bundle-plugin to create OSGi compliance jars. It generates expected OSGi MANIFEST, except Import-Service and Export-Service.

According to http://wiki.osgi.org/wiki/Import-Service, using Import-Service is deprecated. No wonder I failed to start a consumer bundle in distributed fabric mode (cluster). The bundle's MANIFEST contains Import-Service entry which causes it to wait (grace period). It started perfectly as I remove that entry manually.

So, how to configure maven-bundle-plugin to exclude Import-Service and Export-Service from it's generated JARs? It's really troublesome if I have to remove the entry manually.

Thanks

Comment: I don't get it... these headers would only be present in your generated manifest if they were specified explicitly in the POM, e.g. `<Export-Service>...</Export-Service>`. So just remove those entries...

Comment: You should try it with version 2.3.7. I even added empty <Import-Service> to prevent the entry. Sadly, it failed.

Comment: I'm one of the developers of bnd. I know that no version of bnd automatically adds this header. So I'm very curious where it might be coming from.

Comment: @NeilBartlett, I see the same problem with version 2.3.7 of bundle-plugin. Import-Service and Export-Service are added to header automatically.

Comment: @mhshams Version 2.3.7 of maven-bundle-plugin is over two years old. But still I don't know of any version that would add Import/Export-Service automatically, without it being explicitly specified in either the POM or an ancestor POM.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Inside instructions element for plugin configuration you may add:

```
<_removeheaders>Import-Service,Export-Service</_removeheaders>
```

This is equivalent of -removehaders flag in bnd. Instruction itself is described on [bnd website](https://bnd.bndtools.org/instructions/removeheaders.html).